# On python I'm running a command where i want it to say the day and then the date for example Wednesday the 7th

Tags: python, date, time

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
import time
datestr2 = time.strftime("%d")
import dateutil.parser
start_time_local = "2010-08-07T00:00:00+10:00"
weekday = dateutil.parser.parse(start_time_local).strftime('%A')
print (weekday + " The " + datestr2),
if datestr2 =="01"or datestr2 =="02" or datestr2 =="03"or datestr2 =="04"or datestr2 =="05"or datestr2 =="06"or datestr2 =="07":
    print "th"
else:
    print
```

But when I run this it comes up with: Saturday The 07 th I would like it to say Saturday The 7th instead how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
datestr = time.strftime("%-d")
```

should give you the result you want. [This page](http://strftime.org/) is a great resource, I highly recommend bookmarking it.

Also, your `if` statement is way too repetitive. Try this (correcting for the fact that we now have correct format):

```
if datestr[-1] in ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']:
    print 'th'
```

This checks the last character of `datestr` and compares it to a list. Much easier than what you were doing.